# using regex to filter phone nos with exploits

Tags: php, regex

I am filtering numbers from text. Number may contains some digits in word format. So it should flter out such numbers too.

```
$arrwords = array_flip(array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine'));
$s = "my long STRING with 124 mynumberis 8989243three some Numbers 402three1345233 4023one345233";
$sanitised = array();    
foreach (explode(" ", $s) as $tocken) {
    $num = strtr(strtolower($word), $arrwords);
    if(is_numeric($num))
        array_push($sanitised,$tocken);
}
print_r($sanitised);
```

I want to use regex here. Only those number which matches in regex should be filtered out.

```
        foreach ($dbwords as $dbword){
            $pattern = '/^(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
            preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
            print_r($matches);
}
```

Example:

nos: `203three345one56`

first code would be able to filter this number. But as this number is matching in code to it should be considered.

`100`

This number will be filtered in code1, but as it does not fit in code2 regex, it should not be filtered and matched.

Note: I dont want to replace number with `*`. I just want to put all filtered number into array

**UPDATE**

PLEASE SEE DEMO CODE: http://ideone.com/OIDRwj

Input:

my long STRING with 124 mynumberis 8989243three some Numbers 402three1345233 4023one345233

Expected output:

all numbers which which also belongs to regex match should be pushed into array.

Currently out put:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 124
    [1] => 8989243three
    [2] => 402three1345233
    [3] => 4023one345233
)
```

but 124 does not match in regex, so regex should be added at last such that it filters such number and result should be like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8989243three
    [1] => 402three1345233
    [2] => 4023one345233
)
```

Comment: Any input/output examples so that anyone can test it out if they have something?

Comment: @Sam: I added comment there, but no response. In that answer I got same thing which I already implemented and mentioned in question. That's why I need to create new thread

Comment: @Jerry: I added more description and text example. let me know if you need more explaination

Comment: Just something I think is worth pointing out: you don't make a regex choose what to match and what not to match. You change the regex to make it match what's required and what's not. I really don't understand your question, or what you are trying to do, so let me ask: Are you trying to get all the numbers with number names in them?

Comment: Yes, all the numbers with number name in them. But I want user input value should not change in output